# Crosstab/cross over query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Given data looks like

```
PLI_ID   OWN_ID   DCSF_ID   SCH_NAME          PREMIUM1 PREMIUM2  DESCRIPTION  
901      2        1000     Dfe-School 1        86.40     7.20    Heads, Deps
902      2        1000     Dfe-School 2        403.30    8.40    Relief Bursar
903      2        1000     Dfe-School 3        327.00    8.40    £10.00 
904      2        1000     Dfe-School 4        381.50    8.40    £11.00 
905      2        1000     Dfe-School 5        152.60    8.40    Teaching staff
```

Expected data to look like

```
School          £10.00  £11.00  Heads, Deps  Relief Bursar  Teaching staff  Total
Dfe-School 1                            
Dfe-School 2                            
Dfe-School 3                            
Dfe-School 4                            

Total                                                                  [Pre-Total]
```

I am not sure whether to write a Cross Tab or Cross Over query, as suggested. Let me know, if need more explanation.

My query uses around 6 tables and it looks like this:

```
SELECT PolicyLine.PLI_POS_Id, Policy.POL_OWN_Id, Policy.POL_DCSF, School.SCH_Name, PolicyLine.PLI_Premium, CoverPremium.CPR_Premium, StaffCategory.SCA_Description FROM
School 
INNER JOIN Policy ON School.SCH_OWN_Id = Policy.POL_OWN_Id AND School.SCH_DCSF = Policy.POL_DCSF 
INNER JOIN PolicyLine ON Policy.POL_Id = PolicyLine.PLI_POL_Id 
INNER JOIN CoverOption ON PolicyLine.PLI_COP_Id = CoverOption.COP_Id 
INNER JOIN  CoverPremium ON CoverOption.COP_Id = CoverPremium.CPR_COP_Id AND Policy.POL_OWN_Id = CoverPremium.CPR_OWN_Id 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN StaffCategory ON CoverOption.COP_SCA_Id = StaffCategory.SCA_
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s: I just did. Hope this is better now.

Comment: you should really use the "code samples" button (that's what I did - yet again) and **not** use the `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your existing query you would use something like this:

```
SELECT School.SCH_Name school,
  [£10.00], [£11.00], 
  [Heads, Deps], [Relief Bursar], [Teaching staff]
FROM
(
  SELECT PolicyLine.PLI_POS_Id, 
    Policy.POL_OWN_Id, 
    Policy.POL_DCSF, 
    School.SCH_Name, 
    PolicyLine.PLI_Premium, 
    CoverPremium.CPR_Premium, 
    StaffCategory.SCA_Description 
  FROM School 
  INNER JOIN Policy 
    ON School.SCH_OWN_Id = Policy.POL_OWN_Id 
    AND School.SCH_DCSF = Policy.POL_DCSF 
  INNER JOIN PolicyLine 
    ON Policy.POL_Id = PolicyLine.PLI_POL_Id 
  INNER JOIN CoverOption 
    ON PolicyLine.PLI_COP_Id = CoverOption.COP_Id 
  INNER JOIN  CoverPremium 
    ON CoverOption.COP_Id = CoverPremium.CPR_COP_Id 
    AND Policy.POL_OWN_Id = CoverPremium.CPR_OWN_Id 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN StaffCategory 
    ON CoverOption.COP_SCA_Id = StaffCategory.SCA_
) x
PIVOT
(
  sum(PLI_Premium)
  for SCA_Description in([£10.00], [£11.00], 
                     [Heads, Deps], [Relief Bursar], [Teaching staff])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1374/3)

Comment: I did exactly like that but I get all other column values NULL except, School Names, What could be the issue? 

`SELECT School_Names AS School, [0] as "10.00 Non Teaching", [1] as "11.00 Non Teaching", [2] as "Head, Deps & Seniors", [3] as "Relief Bursar", [4] as "Teaching Staff", PLI_Premium as Total FROM ( MAIN INNER QUERY) AS ST PIVOT ( SUM(CPR_Premium) FOR Head_Names IN ([0], [1], [2], [3],[4]) ) AS PT ORDER BY PT.School_Names`

Comment: @Vinoo Based on the data that you posted your fields in the `PIVOT` `FOR Head_Names IN ([0], [1], [2], [3],[4])` don't match.  These should be the names that appear in the column so it should be `[£10.00], [£11.00], [Heads, Deps], [Relief Bursar], [Teaching staff]`

Comment: I tried replacing [0] as [ £8 per hour] which is the value in Description (Last column) but it still displays the NULL Value. Any thoughts?

Comment: what are the values in the description column?

Comment: [£8 per hour], [£9 per hour], [£10 per hour], [£11 per hour], [£12 per hour], [£13 per hour],[£14 per hour],[£15 per hour],[£16 per hour],[£17 per hour],[£18 per hour],[£19 per hour],[£20 per hour],[£21 per hour],[£22 per hour],[£23 per hour],[£24 per hour],[HeadTeacher Support],[Relief Bursar],[Snr Teaching Staff],[Teaching Staff]

Comment: You would need to use those values in the `description` part of the `PIVOT`, then you need to select the field to perform the `Sum()` on - based on your initial post - `PLI_Premium`

Comment: Ok great, I am getting some near to what I want and Thanks for that :) Further to my problem, I am getting multiple rows for School names, the first column and I tried to apply Group By statement, so that it should display a single school name and individual amount under [£8],[£9] and so on, and total of [£8],[£9] so on the last column which Total. But it gives error saying "Invalid column name 'PLI_Premium'", this is because I am using PLI_Premium in first Select statement, then after Pivot SUM(PLI_PREMIUM). What do you say?

Comment: take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1374/6) to show you how to get the Totals - use a `UNION ALL` to add a last line with the totals. As far as the duplicate rows, you might have to remove some of the fields you are returning to drop the duplicates.

Comment: Alright, I did something like this in Outer Select Statement

SUM([£10 per hour])as "10.00 Non Teaching", SUM([£11 per hour])as "11.00 Non Teaching", SUM([HeadTeacher Support])as "Head, Deps & Seniors",SUM([Relief Bursar])as "Relief Bursar",SUM([Snr Teaching Staff])as "Snr Teaching Staff",SUM([Teaching Staff])as "Teaching Staff" --, SUM(PLI_PREMIUM) as Total

and I am getting sum of columns and grouped school name as expected. Now how do I get the total of columns to a last row called Total. Many thanks for direction.

Comment: You are champ, can I replace the query window to my actual query and can you have a look at it and tell me whether I am doing correct and how to get the total of row in last column?

Comment: You will need to provide the link to the SQL fiddle you run.

Comment: What I can see a Column total, but I need the row Total of individual rows in Total Column and than Total of individual Totals in Last Row, Let me know, if I am clear to you. Thanks

Comment: @Vinoo to get the final column with the total, you will need to just create a new column by adding the others together. `[£10.00] + [£11.00] + [Heads, Deps] + [Relief Bursar] + [Teaching staff]`

Comment: I tried this already but I get the NULL in a total column when I sum up all columns, but if I specify only one column, it displays the value of that column and not null. I am pasting what I doing. Please let me know, what I am doing wrong. Thanks

SUM([£10 per hour] + [£11 per hour] + [£12 per hour] + [£13 per hour] + [£14 per hour] + [£15 per hour] + [£16 per hour] + [£17 per hour] + [£18 per hour] + [£19 per hour] + [£20 per hour] + [£21 per hour] + [£22 per hour]  + [HeadTeacher Support] + [Relief Bursar] + [Snr Teaching Staff] + [Teaching Staff]) as Total

Comment: Cool, COALESCE saved my life. it was nullifying the result if any of the column has null value in it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `PIVOT` query, but from your example it's hard to tell what that should look like.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable 
PIVOT 
(SUM(Premium) FOR sch_name in ([£10.00],[£11.00],[Heads, Deps],[Relief Bursar],[Teaching staff]))
```

Comment: I have edited the question to show how does my query looks like. Thanks

Comment: I tried this, `SELECT School_Names AS School, SUM(PolicyLine.PLI_Premium), [0] as "10.00 Non Teaching", [1] as "11.00 Non Teaching", [2] as "Head, Deps & Seniors", [3] as "Relief Bursar", [4] as "Teaching Staff" FROM (MAIN QUERY) AS ST PIVOT ( SUM(PLI_Premium) FOR Head_Names IN ([0], [1], [2], [3],[4]) ) AS PT ORDER BY PT.School_Names` But except School Names all other columns are coming as NULL, Any ideas?